# AVCaptureSession Swift 3 bad exec issue?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, ios10, avcapturesession

I am trying to set up a custom camera within swift 3 for iOS 10.1.

I keep getting the error message below

> " [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   Reading from public effective user settings. "

I have tried adding "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" into info.plist, and the microphone one, but still have the issue.

Sometimes when I disconnect my iPhone from code the message to authorise the camera comes up, almost as if it was "stuck" and "stopped" from coming up?

Does anyone know how to get around using AVCaptureStillImageOutput? It has been deprecated in iOS 10 onwards, and I want to make my app a little bulletproof for the future.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)
    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front{
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))!{
                    captureSession?.addInput(input)
                    stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
                }
                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput))! {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                    previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                    captureSession?.startRunning()
                }
            } catch{
                print("Error Occured when trying get camera")
            }
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue!

Correct code below:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // setting up the camera session
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front{
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))!{
                    captureSession?.addInput(input)
                    stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
                    stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput))! {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                    previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                    captureSession?.startRunning()
                    }
                }
            } catch{
                print("Error Occured when trying get camera")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That starts the camera, but how do you present it on the screen? Sorry Im newbie with the camera on IOS 10.

Comment: I mean, once you link a UIView in the storyboard with @IBOullet var cameraView: UIView! the camera doesn't show (Yes, the camera permissions are set in info.plist)